# regex replace spaces between dollar signs

Tags: regex, replace, spaces

how can i replace the spaces between two dollar sign?

with this regex everything work fine, i can remove the spaces between R and R.

> \s(?![^\R]*(\R|$))
>   [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elQxQ.png)

but when i use dollar sign instead R, it doesn't work. Maybe there are some special way for dollar sign.

> \s(?![^\$]*(\$|$))
>   [result with dollar sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsy6k.png)

EDIT: Programming language: PHP

Comment: You can try `\s+(?=[^$]*\$[^$]*$)` [like this](https://regex101.com/r/cA2aB6/1) if there can only occure one pair of dollars in string. Else you need to check all the string for being inside balanced dollar signs by something [like this regex](https://regex101.com/r/gL4nI9/1) `\s+(?!(?:(?:[^$]*\$){2})*[^$]*$)`

Comment: I want to meet really with this person, who downvotes all regex questions without to read complete question. I understand, it's my first day here, but it doesn't mean, that i have no idea to use this platform. I'm here about 6 years.. It's really unwarranted!

Comment: Thanks bobble bubble, it's work perfect!

Comment: With very long input, this approach is not efficient. I suggest using a simple `\$[^$]+\$` and replace the spaces in the match evauator/lamda expression, and all the similar method your programming language provides.

Comment: BTW, in PCRE and Boost, `\R` means a newline sequence. What language is it for? As the [regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) states, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.

Comment: Your first result is not doing what you think it's doing; `\R` is not the same as `R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\s+(?!(?:(?:[^$]*\$){2})*[^$]*$)` pattern suggested in one of the comments involves a lot of backtracking, but is highly inefficient and can even cause a program freeze.

Here is how I would do it in PHP (replacing a space in between `$` symbols with a hyphen):

```
$re = '~\$[^$]+\$~'; 
$str = "\$ words words \$ \$ words words \$ \$ words words \$ \$ words words \$"; 
$result = preg_replace_callback($re, function($m) {
    return str_replace(" ", "-", $m[0]);
}, $str);
echo $result;
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Ji1pth)

With `\$[^$]+\$` pattern, we match the whole substrings between two dollar symbols, and inside the `preg_replace_callback`, we can further manipulate the replacement by applying the `str_replace` to all the matches.

Comment: You are right, this way seems better. I mark this as answer. Thank you both for help!

Comment: Hi @Wiktor Stribiżew, I have a another question, can you tell me how i do this: I want to put some string to start of first $ sign  and some string to end of other $ sign. Is that possible? For example: "$ words words $" to "<b>$-words-words-$</b>"

Comment: Like [`return "<b>".str_replace(" ", "-", $m[0]) . "</b>";`](http://ideone.com/SOsxVM)?

Comment: ohh, I thought i need one more preg_replace to that =)  Thank you.. I think this will work.

Comment: I have another question. This regex remove all \f or \ charachters. Actually i need them, because it's math formula. For example: "$\frac{1+sin(x)}{y}$" and the result: "$rac{1+sin(x)}{y}$".

Comment: It is not true. `"\f"` is an escape sequence, and the `str_replace(" ", "-", $m[0])` does not replace the `\f` escape sequence. Check your code, it is not the issue with my code. With `[^$]+` you match *all* characters other than a literal `$` (all escape sequences, etc. included).

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/38448ccc521cae9309f6f856e0eca211deb8f530 

You can check here

Comment: No need, I see what you mean. Check [this demo](https://ideone.com/Waf5I1). See the difference: `"\f"` (one symbol) != `'\f'` (two symbols).

Comment: Hi Wiktor, i have a question again; some math formula has "\" after dollar sign and with this regex i can't choose this formulas properly. Is there any way to solve this problem? Example of problematic formulas: $\ rac{1+sin} $

Comment: What is the rule? See [how the current regex matches this string](https://regex101.com/r/cW7sQ4/1). Please modify the regex fiddle to show what you need. I'd appreciate a sample input with expected output.

Comment: Ok, now i know what's the issue is. Some formulas start with two dollar sign and some only one. Type-1: $\ rac{1+sin} $ , Type-2: $$\ rac{1+sin} $$, please check this: https://regex101.com/r/cW7sQ4/2

Comment: So, you need a regex to match between `$$`s? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/cW7sQ4/4) with `'/[$]{2}.*?[$]{2}/s'`.

Comment: is it possible to combine two regex? this '~\$[^$]+\$~' with this  '/[$]{2}.*?[$]{2}/s' ?

Comment: Use alternation, people here do not like conditional expressions (got a lot of crtique for showing that `(?(grp1)yes|no)` construct yesterday). [`(?s)(?:[$]{2}.*?[$]{2}|\$[^$]*\$)`](https://regex101.com/r/cW7sQ4/5). And if you need to get the contents in-between, use [`(?s)(?|[$]{2}(.*?)[$]{2}|\$([^$]*)\$)`](https://regex101.com/r/cW7sQ4/6) - the result will be in Group 1.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, it's work perfect. You save my life =)